# Push local repository to remote in Github

Tags: git, github

I have a java project that contains one java file called Calculator. I created a repository in Github and I tried to push the local repository to the remote one by following:

First: I created a readme file `echo "# Simple Java calculator" >> README.md`

Second: `git init`

Third: `git add README.md`

Fourth: `git commit -m "simple calculator"`

Fifth: `git remote add origin https://github.com/XXXXX/Calc.git`

Sixth: `git push -u origin master`

After that I checked the repository online and I only found the Read me file. I later figured our I need to add the Calculator file and I tried the following options:

`git add .`

`git push -u origin master`

and this option

`git add Calculator.java`

`git push -u origin master`

but both did not work and the file is not in the remote repository yet. Can someone help me with this

Comment: Did you get any error when trying the `git push -u origin master` in the last two cases? If so, please state the error you got. Also, please try the `git status`, and state the message you get.

Comment: First, you have to commit the changes once you add the files using `git add`, and before you push the changes using `git push` instead of `git push -u origin master`, since I think you only have to use the later when you first created the local branch and need to push it to the remote repo, once you do it the first time, you just need to do a `git push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git uses add to add files to the index. Then commit to commit the files in the index and then push to share your commits with another repository.

Since you've not made a commit, you need to type

`git commit`

after you've done a

`git add`

and before you do a

`git push`

The -u you use to the push command, tells git that master should always push to master on origin, so you just need to use that the first time. From now on it should be enough for you to type:

`git push`

instead of

`git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 1):

After adding the files using,

git add .

You should commit the changes before pushing to the remote repo,

git commit -m "commit message"

Also, you can use the below single command to add and commit,

git commit -am "commit message"